# Tidy evaluation in making multiple panel plots using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap, tidyeval

I have a function to make multi-panel plots using ggplot2:

```
plot_facet <- function(df, var.x, var.y, var.facet) {
  p <- df %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x = {{var.x}}, y = {{var.y}})) +
    geom_point()    
  
   if(!is_missing(var.facet)) p <- p + facet_grid({{var.facet}} ~ .)
  
  return(p)
}
```

The following call works as expected:

```
plot_facet(mtcars, mpg, hp) + facet_grid(cyl ~ .)
```

But this doesn't:

```
plot_facet(mtcars, mpg, hp, cyl)
```

and I got the error message:

> Error in is_reference(x, quote(expr = )) : object 'cyl' not found

I have tried this and it doesn't work either:

```
facet_grid(rows = vars({{var.facet}}))
```

How can I fix it? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be that `is_missing` evaluates too much (to be honest, I don't make too much sense out of its help page). If you just use `missing` (which only operates on the symbol), you can use your `facet_grid(rows = vars({{var.facet}}))` approach:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(magrittr)
library(rlang)

plot_facet <- function(df, var.x, var.y, var.facet) {
  p <- df %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x = {{var.x}}, y = {{var.y}})) +
    geom_point()    
  
  if(!missing(var.facet)) p <- p + facet_grid(rows = vars({{var.facet}}))
  
  return(p)
}

plot_facet(mtcars, mpg, hp, cyl)
```

Alternatively, you can convert `var.facet` to a symbol at the beginning of your function and use this together with `is_missing` and the `rows` argument:

```
plot_facet <- function(df, var.x, var.y, var.facet) {
  var.facet <- ensym(var.facet)
  p <- df %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x = {{var.x}}, y = {{var.y}})) +
    geom_point()    
  
  if(!is_missing(var.facet)) p <- p + facet_grid(rows = vars({{var.facet}}))
  
  return(p)
}

plot_facet(mtcars, mpg, hp, cyl)
```

Comment: That is an unexpected and surprising cause to the problem. If I want to use `facet_grid({{var.facet}} ~.)` instead, converting `var.facet` to a symbol still gives me an error. How should I make it work? Thanks.

Comment: I've tried a little bit but haven't found a solution yet. I have only used the formula notation with `facet_wrap` so far. I'm not completely sure what happens there, but it seems that the formula notation becomes deprecated now, maybe because of this problems with the new style of NSE (e.g. the formula style is called "classic interface" in the man page for `facet_wrap`)?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this approach :

```
library(ggplot2)

plot_facet <- function(df, var.x, var.y, var.facet) {
  var <- deparse(substitute(var.facet)) 
  p <- df %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x = {{var.x}}, y = {{var.y}})) +
    geom_point()    
  
  if(var != '') p <- p + facet_grid(reformulate('.', var))
  
  return(p)
}
```

The both of this works and produces the same output.

```
plot_facet(mtcars, mpg, hp) + facet_grid(cyl ~ .)
plot_facet(mtcars, mpg, hp, cyl)
```